# Error updating android sdk platform for Android 4.4

Tags: android

When i try to update the android 4.4 SDK platform to rev.2. I got **Download interrupted: Unexpected HTTP Status 500** as an error and **Done. Nothing was installed.** message was displayed. I tried again and again but i got the same error.[image]

Comment: step 1. Find SDK Manager in your drive where you install SDK.      Step 2. Right click on SDK Manager & choose Run as administrator   Step 3. Update.

Comment: What to do with that sdk manager?

Comment: I did that but its still not working. same error I am getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTTP Error 500**
The Web server received a valid request from a client but was unable to process it. HTTP 500 errors occur when the server encounters some general technical glitch such as being low on available memory or disk space. A server administrator must fix this problem.  [HTTP Errors](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/networkprotocolsip/tp/http-error-and-status-codes-explained.htm)

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html:

```
Internal Error 500

The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.
```

The problem is not on your end, try again in a bit

Comment: If the problem is with server than why am i able to udate other things? Only this sdk tools i am not able to update.

Comment: Maybe the server cannot retrieve the data it needs for this particular update. There are many possible reasons, depends on how their servers work internally.

Comment: I am still not able to update it. I am trying from last 5 days but still same result.